# NOT a HASH reference

Tags: xml, perl

I am getting the "NOT a HASH reference" error in Perl 5.30.x in line 70 of my code where I am trying to test $xml for its type thus:

I can not figure out how to resolve this issue as I have been away from Perl for quite some time and would appreciate any and all suggestions.

The code follow (I hope!).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use URI;
use LWP::Simple;
use Net::Amazon;
use XML::Simple;
use constant AMAZON_TOKEN => 'amazon token deleted';
use constant DEBUG => 0;

# get our arguments. the first argument is the
# URL to fetch, and the second is the output.
my $url = shift || die "$0 <url> [<output>]\n";
my $output = shift || '/www/htdocs/cloud.html';

# we'll need to fetch the Alexa XML at some point, and
# we'll do it a few different times, so we create a 
# subroutine for it. Using the URI module, we can
# correctly encode a URL with a query. In fact, you'll
# notice the majority of this function is involved with
# this, and at the end we use LWP::Simple to actually
# download and return the XML.
#####################################################
sub fetch_xml {
    my $url = shift;
    $url = "http://$url" unless $url =~ m[^http://];
    warn "Fetching Alexa data for $url\n" if DEBUG;

    my @args = (
        cli => 10,     dat => 'snba',
        ver => '7.0',  url => $url,
    );

    my $base = 'http://data.alexa.com/data';
    my $uri = URI->new( $base );
    $uri->query_form( @args );
    $uri = $uri->as_string;

    return get( $uri );
}

# raw XML is no good for us, though, as we want to extract
# particular items of interest. we use XML::Simple to turn
# the XML into Perl data structures, because it's easier
# than fiddling with event handling (as with XML::Parser
# or XML::SAX), and we know there's only a small amount of
# data. we want the list of related sites and the list of
# related products. we extract and return both.
#####################################################
sub handle_xml {
    my $page = shift;
    my $xml = XMLin( $page );
    my @related = map {
        {
            asin => $_->{ASIN},
            title => $_->{TITLE},
            href => $xml->{RLS}{PREFIX}.$_->{HREF},
        }
    } @{ $xml->{RLS}{RL} };

    my @products;
    if (ref $xml->{SD}{AMZN}{PRODUCT} eq 'ARRAY') {
        @products = map { $_->{ASIN} } @{ $xml->{SD}{AMZN}{PRODUCT} };
    } else { @products = $xml->{SD}{AMZN}{PRODUCT}{ASIN}; }

    return ( \@related, \@products );
}

# Functions done; now for the program:
warn "Start URL is $url\n" if DEBUG;
my @products; # running accumulation of product ASINs

{
    my $page = fetch_xml( $url );
    my ($related, $new_products) = handle_xml( $page );
    @products = @$new_products; # running list

    for (@$related) {
        my $xml = fetch_xml( $_->{href} );
        my ($related, $new_products) = handle_xml( $page );
        push @products, @$new_products;
    }
}

# We now have a list of products in @products, so
# we'd best do something with them. Let's look
# them up on Amazon and see what their titles are.
my $amazon = Net::Amazon->new( token => AMAZON_TOKEN );
my %products = map { $_ => undef } @products;

for my $asin ( sort keys %products ) {
    warn "Searching for $asin...\n" if DEBUG;
    my $response = $amazon->search( asin => $asin );
    my @products = $response->properties;
    die "ASIN is not unique!?" unless @products == 1;
    my $product = $products[0];
    $products{$asin} = {
        name => $product->ProductName,
        price => $product->OurPrice,
        asin => $asin,
    };
}

# Right. We now have name, price, and
# ASIN. Let's output an HTML report:
{
    umask 022;
    warn "Writing to $output\n" if DEBUG;
    open my $fh, '>', $output or die $!;
    print $fh "<html><head><title>Cloud around $url</title></head><body>";
    if (keys %products) {
        print $fh "<table>";
        for my $asin (sort keys %products) {
            my $data = $products{$asin};
            printf $fh "<tr><td>".
                       "<a href=\"http://amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/%s\">".
                       "%s</a></td> <td>%s</td></tr>",
                       @{$data}{qw( asin name price )};
        }
        print $fh "</table>";
    }
    else { print $fh "No related products found.\n"; }
    print $fh "</body></html>\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code so that we can see what might be failing?

Comment: Inspect `ref($xml)` to see what type of reference it is

Comment: Are you using [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple)?

Comment: Some unspecified code is expecting a reference to a hash (perhaps among other things), but it's getting something else it doesn't expect instead. We can't help you more without more.

Comment: when I print $xml this is the output; "XML: HASH(0x3ba8fa8)"

Comment: Here are all my 'use' statements: 
use strict;
use URI;
use LWP::Simple;
use Net::Amazon;
use XML::Simple;

Comment: How can I post the code? Its to big to fit in a comment.

Comment: I think I was able to post the code after I edited the original question to add the code to the end of the question.

Comment: The "_line 70_" of what you posted, where you say the error is, is `my @products; #...`.  That clearly is not in error. On the other hand, there are many other places where variables are used as hashrefs so which could be in error.   We can't really help you out if you don't do your part.

Comment: See <http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE> and switch to LibXML to save yourself further pain. But if you insist, then at least apply <http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple#STRICT-MODE>.

Comment: zdim,I am sorry that I was not specific enough. That this the block where the error occurs. Right now the error occurs at line 65 in the my product block;" return ( \@related, \@products );"

Comment: Here is the output from the code I posted:

Not a HASH reference at C:\Users\Bonnie\My Documents\Alexa2.pl line 65 (#1)
    (F) Perl was trying to evaluate a reference to a hash value, but found a
    reference to something else instead.  You can use the ref() function to
    find out what kind of ref it really was.  See perlref.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Not a HASH reference at C:\Users\Bonnie\My Documents\Alexa2.pl line 65.
        main::handle_xml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\x{d}\x{a}\x
{d}\x{a}<!-- Need more Alex"...) called at .........line 83

Comment: So at line `return ( \@related, \@products );` ?  No, can't have a "_Not a HASH reference_" error for that.  Example:  code like `$var->{...}` treats `$var` as a hash reference and if what is in `$var` in fact _isn't_ that then you'd have that error. So go though the code, print out values of variables etc to find out where things are different than what you expect.  (I don't understand what errors you are getting from this description in the above comments.  You should edit the question to add this information, and be careful how you do it so that it is clear.)

Comment: If you want to address a certain user -- like in the above message addressed to me -- prepend their name with "at", so @zdim, and they get notified of the comment.  Otherwise they won't know (people often don't return to "check" these pages after they leave a comment, and much less so the next day).

Answer (score 1):

You're using [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple). That is a mistake. Even the documentation for the module agrees with me:

> **STATUS OF THIS MODULE**
>
> The use of this module in new code is strongly
>   discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more
>   straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)
>   is highly recommended and you can refer to [Perl XML::LibXML by Example](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/)
>   for a tutorial introduction.
>
> [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) is another excellent alternative.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options
>   (some of which have unfortunate defaults) and the arbitrary ways in
>   which these options interact - often producing unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new
>   features are unlikely to be added.

Without seeing your XML it's hard to be sure, but this is what I think has happened. XML::Simple is famously inconsistent in the data structures that it returns. A small change in the input document can have major ramifications for the data structure you get back. It's very common for what was a hash reference to turn into an array reference on a very similar document.

My recommendation is to stop using XML::Simple. Personally, I'd replace it with XML::LibXML.