# Extracting value in XML file

Tags: xml, perl

This is my XML format:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>..</C>
    <D>..</D>
    <E>..</E>
  </B>
</A>
```

And here's my code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
open(my $fh, '<', '/tmp/abc.xml');
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin($fh) or die "Failed to find $fh";
my $value = $data->{'B'};
print $value->{'C'}
```

Giving error:

> Not a HASH reference.

Can you please explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, edited my code in the post. the code runs but doesnt print anything.

Comment: The error does not happen for me with the exact XML you've provided. So my guess is that your actual XML is different, like having another `<B>...</B>` on the same level as the existing one (which will throw this problem since now an ARRAY is created not a HASH). Please provide something which can actually be reproduced. See also [NOT a HASH reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993628/not-a-hash-reference) about the status of the module which explicitly states *"The use of this module in new code is strongly discouraged."*.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, Im trying to read :
http://www.rfs.nsw.gov.au/feeds/fdrToban.xml

Comment: @Jens, No, `$data->{B}` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Re "*Can you please explain where Im going wrong?*", You went wrong when you decided to use a module that's virtually impossible to use correctly despite its own documentation telling you not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going wrong in a couple of ways: First, using an obsolete module for XML parsing whose documentation is full of warnings to not use it, and not using an XPath expression to get at the data you want. The following uses [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);
# my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => '/tmp/abc.xml');

my @nodes = $xml->findnodes('/A/B/C');
for my $node (@nodes) {
    say $node->textContent();
}

__DATA__
<A>
  <B>
    <C>..</C>
    <D>..</D>
    <E>..</E>
  </B>
</A>
```

---

Or using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig =
    XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => { '/A/B/C' => sub { say $_[1]->text } });

$twig->parse(\*DATA);
# $twig->parsefile('/tmp/abc.xml');

__DATA__
<A>
  <B>
    <C>..</C>
    <D>..</D>
    <E>..</E>
  </B>
</A>
```

Comment: Thanks, for anyone stumbling across:

https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/

Comment: My rule for XML::Simple is that you can use it until you run into your first problem with it. Then you have to stop using. :)